# insert query using django-models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

DB structure

User, user has multiple events, events has multiple attendees.

User Model:

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    org_url = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    office_username = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    office_email = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    isdeleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    createdon = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    modifiedon = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
```

Event Model:

```
from django.db import models
from .user import User


class OEvent(models.Model):
    frk_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    o_event_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    starts_at = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    ends_at = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    event_title = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)

    isdeleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    createdon = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    modifiedon = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
```

Attendee Model:

```
from django.db import models
from .o_events import OEvent

class OEventAttendee(models.Model):
    frk_o_event = models.ForeignKey(OEvent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

I can insert events against a user like this:

```
user.oevent_set.create(
        o_event_id=nData['Id'],
        location=nData['Location']['DisplayName'],
        starts_at=startdt,
        ends_at=enddt,
        event_title=nData['Subject'],
        isdeleted=False,
        createdon=createdon,
        modifiedon=modifiedon
    )
```

What is the best, easy, short way to add attendees like this?

I'm assuming that there must be something We can add `event_attendees list = attendees array` after modifiedon field. But couldn't find anything like that.

Comment: what about using `serializer` and create instances using a custom `.create()` method ?

Answer (score 0):

in your "OEventAttendee" model you expect a "OEvent" instance so you **need to create first** "OEvent" instance then you can create atendees using Django [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method

Answer (score -1):

What you can add is `related_name="events"` for event on user field and for attendee `related_name="attendees"` so you can then do

`user.events.attendees.all()` and after you creates an attendee you can do `user.events.attendees.add(atendee)` in a for loop

Comment: no actually I have only user, and I am creating event and I want to create event with attendees. we dont want to create event and then add attendees. If its possible.

Comment: you have to create the event first then you can when looping through all the attendees do `atend = OEventAttendee(frk_o_event=event ...)`

Comment: ok, this means I can't do this with in this create function :(

Comment: yeah this is the way it's always been